# How To search name from database using id from ajax and set that name to the next field in the form automatically this means ajax response

Tags: php, ajax

This is my code

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
  server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hospital", "root", "");
    // Set the PDO error mode to exception
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());
}

// Attempt search query execution
try {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['term'])) {
        // create prepared statement
        $sql = "SELECT am_first_name, am_middle_name,am_last_name FROM 
    admission_master WHERE am_ip_no LIKE :term";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $term = $_REQUEST['term'] . '%';
        // bind parameters to statement
        $stmt->bindParam(':term', $term);
        // execute the prepared statement
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                // echo "<p>" . $row['am_ip_no'] . "</p>";
                echo "<p>" . $row['am_first_name'] . "</p>";
                echo "<p>" . $row['am_middle_name'] . "</p>";
                echo "<p>" . $row['am_last_name'] . "</p>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
        }
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $e->getMessage());
}

// Close statement
unset($stmt);

// Close connection
unset($pdo);
?>
```

Font End Code Is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>PHP Live MySQL Database Search</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                font-family: Arail, sans-serif;
            }
            /* Formatting search box */
            .search-box{
                width: 300px;
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            .search-box input[type="text"]{
                height: 32px;
                padding: 5px 10px;
                border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            .result{
                position: absolute;        
                z-index: 999;
                top: 100%;
                left: 0;
            }
            .search-box input[type="text"], .result{
                width: 100%;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            /* Formatting result items */
            .result p{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 7px 10px;
                border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
                border-top: none;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .result p:hover{
                background: #f2f2f2;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#h input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function () {
                    /* Get input value on change */
                    var inputVal = $(this).val();
                    var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
                    if (inputVal.length) {
                        $.get("sqlsearch.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function (data) {
                            // Display the returned data in browser
                            resultDropdown.html(data);
                        });
                    } else {
                        resultDropdown.empty();
                    }
                });

                // Set search input value on click of result item
                $(document).on("click", ".result p", function () {
                    $(this).parents(".search-
                            box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());

                    $(this).parents("#autoFill").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
                    $(this).parent(".result").empty();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="search-box" id="h">
            <input type="text"  placeholder="Search ..." />
            <div class="result"></div>
        </div>


        <div id="autoFill">
            <input type="text" placeholder="name automatically ..." />
            <div class="res"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How To search name from the database using id from ajax and set that name to the next field in the form automatically this means ajax response.